# Calculate "Working hours " based on IN and OUT time Employee Attendance Power bi

Tags: sql, datetime, powerbi, dax

I am using Power bi and I would like to calculate the working hours of my employees based on the time they entered and left the company.
Here is a sample of data[image: Att_tabel]
the supposed total hours should be 7 hours and 8 minutes.
SO, the time where the employee was out and do nothing. In my case, I should exclude the time starting from  OUT 2:04:20 to IN 3:09:46    about 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the next `out` for each `in` and take the difference:

```
select t.employee_id,
       sum(datediff(second, local_time, next_local_time)) as diff_seconds
from (select t.*,
             lead(local_time) over (partition by employee_id order by local_time) as next_local_time
     from t
    ) t
where action = 'IN'
group by t.employee_id;
```

Note:  This assumes that `IN`s and `OUT`s are interleaved, so there are no rows with the same action in a row.

This also gives the result in seconds -- which can be converted to decimal hours or any other particular format you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how do I implement this in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI/Power Query, assuming your table is the same structure as your post you can create a new table with the following script. In this script `yourSource` is reference to your table.

```
let
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(yourSource,{{"EmployeeID", Order.Ascending}, {"LOCAL_TIME", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Employee_In_Out_Index", each if [Action] = "IN" then [Index] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Employee_In_Out_Index"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Index"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Employee_In_Out_Index", "EmployeeID", "Action", "LOCAL_TIME"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Reordered Columns", List.Distinct(#"Reordered Columns"[Action]), "Action", "LOCAL_TIME"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Time Difference", each [OUT] - [IN])
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

In the new table, each record is for one in-out. There is a `Time Difference` column here which you can use in your calculations.

[image]