# Calculate "Working Hours" based on IN and OUT time Employee Attendance

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am using Power bi and I would like to calculate the working hours of employees based on the time they entered and left the company. Here is a sample of data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIWS0.png

Each row tells me, by use of the badge on the turnstile, the date, hour and the direction of the action.
I want the Power BI to calculate the working hours by the difference between the first entrance and the last exit date and hours.

I tried to use the M Language code on this resolution: [Calculate "Working hours " based on IN and OUT time Employee Attendance Power bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405180/calculate-working-hours-based-on-in-and-out-time-employee-attendance-power-bi)

The idea of this code is to rearrange the "DateTime" Column, creating 2 columns instead: First In Hour and Last Exit Hour. This means that instead of each rows show the badge usage, this new table shows, on each row, the working hours.
The result didn't work, because the new table kept separating each action (In and Out) on every row instead of put these informations on the new columns "First In Hour" and "Last Exit Hour".

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your questions as asked, but it just seems wrong

This returns the number of minutes from the first IN to the last Out, no matter how far apart they are

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Employee ID"}, {{"ElapsedMinutes", each 
    let a=_,
    b=Table.Sort(Table.SelectRows(a, each [Direction] = "In"),{{"DateTime", Order.Ascending}}){0}[DateTime],
    c=Table.Sort(Table.SelectRows(a, each [Direction] = "Out"),{{"DateTime",  Order.Descending}}){0}[DateTime]
    in Duration.TotalMinutes(c - b), type number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]